# FindBugs scanning external jars

Tags: java, ant, findbugs, build.xml

I am using the following link to create an ant script to run findbugs on a web application:
[Chapter 6. Using the FindBugs™ Ant task](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/anttask.html)

I am setting the **auxClasspath** parameter to my jars folder.

But when i run the task using **ant findbugs** from the command prompt, it takes a very long time(~45 minutes) and the output xml contains analysis of the jars in the **auxClasspath** as well as my source code.

I want only my source code to be analyzed.

This is the code in my build.xml:

```
<taskdef name="findbugs" classname="edu.umd.cs.findbugs.anttask.FindBugsTask"/>
<property name="findbugs.home" value="C:/Software/FindBugs" />
<target name="findbugs" >
    <echo message="Finding Bugs From ${basedir}/src/java"/>
    <findbugs home="${findbugs.home}"
              output="xml:withMessages"
              outputFile="${basedir}\findbugs.xml"
              stylesheet="fancy-hist.xsl"
              timeout="6000000"
              jvmargs="-Xmx1200m">
        <auxClasspath path="${basedir}/Jars/*.jar" />
        <sourcePath path="${basedir}/src/java"/>
        <class location="${basedir}/build/myApp-1.0.jar" />
    </findbugs>
</target>
```

I have added findbugs-ant.jar to lib of my ant installation.
The findbugs directory exists.

Other information:
IDE: Netbeans 7.3
OS:  Microsoft Windows XP
Ant Version: 1.8.4
Find Bugs Version: 2.0.2

**Update**

If i leave out this line:

```
<auxClasspath path="${basedir}/Jars/*.jar" />
```

I get my desired output(i.e. analysis of only my source code).
But it raises a warning:

```
[findbugs] The following classes needed for analysis were missing:
[findbugs]   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet
[findbugs]   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper
[list continues]....
```

Any idea, why find bugs is analyzing jars which it should not analyze(according to the documentation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to track which Jars are being used in the source code.

In the findbugs xml output, i found a line: ${basedir}\Jars\antlr-2.7.2.jar

The findbugs analysis report showed that all the other jars(except antlr-2.7.2.jar) were missing.

There were no more auxClassPath entries. Solved this by specifying each class path entry in a different line.

If anyone has any better ideas, kindly contribute.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following auxClasspath settings to pull in all my jars in my lib folder and all the jars in directories under my lib folder.

```
<auxClasspath>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*/**"/>
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</auxClasspath>
```

Place it inside the findbugs tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove this line

```
<class location="${basedir}/build/myApp-1.0.jar" />
```

Now to try to analyze both jar and source files, that's it takes so long time.

This line is needed and used to find a class if it encounters during analysis of your source.

```
<auxClasspath path="${basedir}/Jars/*.jar" />
```

Maybe to can limit it to only really needed jars, not all in the folder.

Comment: That line is to indicate location of my source files, so that the final output xml contains details about the code for which findbugs is raising a warning.

Comment: That was written by me. Are you referring to some other update?

Comment: @ShivanandaSahu, in my answer.

Comment: Going by what you said, i tried to track which Jars are being used in the source code. In the findbugs xml output, i found a line:  
`<AuxClasspathEntry>${basedir}\Jars\antlr-2.7.2.jar</AuxClasspathEntry>`

The findbugs analysis report contained analysis for all the other jars.
There were no more auxClassPath entries.
We have to specify each class path entry in a different line.